# Django POST Method Unit Test failing with Assertionerror 401

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am writing django unittests for an application which is having modules with HTTP get,put and post methods. I have been [referencing](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing#test-cases) rest_framework's APITestCase method for writing unittest for POST method.

Here is my code for POST method unittest:

```
def test_postByTestCase(self):
    url = reverse('lib:ingredient-detail',args=('123',))
    data = {'name':'test_data','status':'draft','config':'null'}
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

By running this test case I am getting this output:

```
$ python manage.py test lib.IngredientTestCase.test_postByTestCase
```

FDestroying test database for alias 'default'...

======================================================================

### FAIL: test_postByTestCase (lib.tests.IngredientTestCase)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apache2\htdocs\iLab\api\lib\tests.py", line 42, in test_postByTestCase
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 401 != 201

---

Ran 1 test in 5.937s

FAILED (failures=1)

I have tried passing HTTP_AUTHORIZATION token value, but it is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `401` error means that your request is unauthorized. Does the application that you're trying to test require a login? If this is the case, you'll need to set up an authenticated user in your test before trying the `POST` request.

```
# my_api_test.py

def setUp:
    # Set up user
    self.user = User(email="foo@bar.com") # NB: You could also use a factory for this
    password = 'some_password'
    self.user.set_password(password)
    self.user.save()

    # Authenticate client with user
    self.client = Client()
    self.client.login(email=self.user.email, password=password)

def test_postByTestCase(self):
    url = reverse('lib:ingredient-detail',args=('123',))
    data = {'name':'test_data','status':'draft','config':'null'}
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Once you've logged in a user to your client, then you should be able to call your API correctly and see a `201` response.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for help. It helped me to resolve 401 error. but now it is sending me 200, instead of 201.                                it is printing response.data as {'id': u'52fdae0c8faa5412442eafd2', 'success': True}

Comment: Hey, got it working... thanks for your help Jonathan. There were some problem in my application code base. Thanks again!!

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I have the two decorators (login required and api_view) so maybe that's why. Also, I'm testing.